# Type error when dealing with collections of inherited objects

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following methods

```
Rectangle updateRectangle(Rectangle rect);
Collection<Rectangle> updateRectangles(Collection<Rectangle> rects);
```

I have two classes: `Square` and `Rectangle`. `Square` **extends** `Rectangle`.

The following works and has the desired behavior I want:

```
Square updateSquare(Square s) {
  return updateRectangle(s);
}
```

The following gives me a type-error

```
Collection<Square> updateSquare(Collection<Square> squares) {
    return updateRectangles(squares);
}
```

Can someone clarify to me why a `Square` **is a** `Rectangle`, but a collection of `Squares` is **not** a Collection of `Rectangles`? Is there something I can do to cleanly get around this "incompatible types" error?

Exact error: `java: incompatible types: java.util.Collection<Square> cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<Rectangle>`

Comment: this article can be useful for you> https://dzone.com/articles/how-do-generic-subtypes-work

Comment: That is because **generics are invariant**. Jon Skeet explained it well in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po/2745301#2745301).

Comment: I get a compilation error with your `updateSquare()` method: `error: incompatible types: Rectangle cannot be converted to Square`, pointing to the fact that `updateRectangle` returns a `Rectangle` and that Java cannot convert this back to a `Square`.

Comment: `updateSquare()` and `updateRectange()` are really bad method names.  `update()` and `updateList()` are much better.  Then `Rectangle` can overwrite the `Square.update()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called covariance/invariance/contravariance.

A list of rectangles is not a list of squares or vice versa: Lists are invariant.

Plain jane data types.. yes, there all squares are also rectangles: These are covariant.

That's because.. they fundamentally are. Here, let's take a trip to imaginary land and, nestled between unicorns and rainbows, we act as if lists of Xs and lists of Ys are covariant on the data type, e.g. that a list of squares is also a list of rectangles:

```
List<Square> squares = new ArrayList<Square>();
squares.add(new Square(20));
List<Rectangle> rectangles = squares;
rectangles.add(new Rectangle(10, 30));

Square s = squares.get(1); // UHOH!!!!!
```

And as we retrieve our square from our list of squares and notice the object we so obtain does not, in fact, have equal sides, our imaginary world crashes and disappears in a poof of smoke and leprecaun tears.

Awwwwww!

---

So, what's going wrong here?

The `add` (and add-likes such as `addAll`) op is in fact **contravariant**. The relationship is reversed! If I add a square to a list, that's okay.. if it is a list of square or any **supertype**. You can add squares to a list-o-squares, or a list-o-rectangles, or a list-o-objects. This is in reverse from the `get(int idx)` operation, which is **covariant**: I can assign the result of `listOfSquares.get(0)` to `Square`, or `Rectangle`, or `Object`.

In java, you pick your own variance. The above code snippet from unicorn land does not compile here in the real world. Specifically, the line `List<Rectangle> rectangles = squares;` won't compile, because by default generics acts invariant, thus making a list of squares not compatible with a list of rectangles.

But you control it, you can change it. Here, let's introduce covariance:

```
List<Square> squares = new ArrayList<Square>();
squares.add(new Square(20));
List<? extends Rectangle> rectangles = squares;
rectangles.add(new Rectangle(10, 30));

Square s = squares.get(1); // UHOH!!!!!
```

We have now introduced covariance: The definition of the `rectangles` object reads: "Covariant on rectangle". This is fine and now this line **compiles and runs just fine**.

But the error moves: Java knows that given that you demanded covariance, that all `add` methods need to disappear, because those aren't compatible with the notion of covariance. And so it is: The line `rectangles.add(new Rectangle(10, 30))` **will not compile**. In fact, for any `List<? extends Whatever>`, the add method is not invokable (unless you pass `null`, but that's a fluke that's mostly irrelevant to variance).

---

You can even opt into contravariance:

```
List<Square> squares = new ArrayList<Square>();
squares.add(new Square(20));
List<? super Rectangle> rectangles = squares;
rectangles.add(new Rectangle(10, 30));

Square s = squares.get(1); // UHOH!!!!!
```

And now we have a list of contravariant rectangles. As expected, the world is now flipped upside down: Add is fine in this world. But get() is an issue.

First of all, a list of squares is not assignable to a list of rectangles if we're in contravariant world, so that line won't compile. But a list of objects would be, so, this will compile:

```
List<Object> o = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<? super Rectangle> r = o; // this is fine!
r.add(new Rectangle(10, 20)); // so is this
Rectangle z = r.get(0); // but not this
```

now add works fine, but get doesn't. Which shows up not as 'you cant call get at all', but as: the type of the 'get' invocation is just java.lang.Object.

This makes sense: You can assign a list of rectangles or a list of objects to a `List<? super Rectangle>` variable, because adding a rectangle to either of these is fine. When getting values out, best I can do for you is to guarantee you that no matter what, it's an object, so that's all you get.

### So, how do I fix this?

Weirdly, you probably can't. It sounds like `updateRectangles` needs to both 'read' items from the list as well as 'write' items to it.

If all you were going to do is read from the list and you want the guarantee that whatever falls out, it's at least a rectangle, that's covariance, so you tell the compiler you opt into that: `void readRectangles(Collection<? extends Rectangle> collection) {}` and you can pass a list-o-squares to this method just fine (and if you try to add to the collection, javac won't let you).

If all you were going to do is write, then.. opt into contravariance: `void addSquares(Collection<? super Square> collection) {}` and you can call `.add(new Square())` on the collection just fine. You can pass your list-o-rectangles or your list-o-squares.

But you want both, so all you get is invariance. What you want isn't really possible, not without resorting to unsafe casts or other hackery.

If you describe exactly what `updateRectangles` actually does, we can help. If you never call .add(), go with `Collection<? extends Rectangle>` and you're good to go.

Comment: Cool, great answer!

Comment: This is a great answer. I can't really go into more details of what the exact use case is, but this points me in a good direction!

Answer (score 2):

Altough Square is a subclass of a Rectangle, Collection of squares is **not a subclass** of Collection of Rectangle from Java's type system point of view. Java expects, that a collection passed to the method will hold instances of exactly Rectangle type. To tell the compiled that a subclasses will also do, you have to use what it's called a bounded wildcard, like this:

```
Collection<? extends Rectangle> updateRectangles(Collection<? extends Rectangle> rects)
```

For more details on generics wildcards see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)